# Are there any .Net libraries to include mapping in a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, maps

I'm wanting to write a simple WinForms application that will be able to plot several locations on a map. Ideally, the application would embed a map that I can programmatically manipulate, and be able to add locations to the map using postal codes.

Is anyone aware of any free maps I can use within my application, ideally with either a .Net interface or a .Net library that wraps its interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only **free** map I know of is [OpenStreeMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), the others (Google, Bing) require licensing. There are a [couple of related projects](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=openstreetmap) on Codeplex.

Comment: The link to the related projects on Codeplex turned up GMap.Net, which wraps several different maps. That project looks ideal.

Comment: Thx for mentioning GMap.Net, looks great!

Answer (score 0):

There are some free maps (with water marks) in the trial version of [Global Mapper](http://www.globalmapper.com/).  [Here](http://www.globalmapper.com/online_data/free_sample.htm) is some of the free sample data.